# Encountered Gradle error while using "flutter build apk" in Flutter project. How to fix it? Thanks

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

```
`C:\Users\Selem'n\Documents\My Projects\vote_app\vote_app> flutter build apk

Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> Failed to run Gradle Worker Daemon
   > Process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 5' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I tried to do `flutter clean`, then `flutter pub get` then `flutter build apk`, I come back with the same problem